# Sum row values of a data frame using R - where each value in the row is evaluated against a condition

Tags: r, row

I have a data frame 20,000 observations and 171 variables. Each value in every row is either a +1, 0 or -1.

I want to be able to sum (or count) the number of 1's in each row and make that number variable number 172.

I have researched this but cannot find a solution.

rowsum() is not suitable as I can't make it conditional like rowsum(df , =1)

The same is the case with apply. For example, the following code won't work :

```
apply(df, 1, sum(=1) ).
```

Is there a way to calculate the conditional sum of a row, where only those values in the row that match the criteria are summed.

Comment: `rowSums(df == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best if you can provide data that people can work with. For example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(col1 = sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 col2 = sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 col3 = sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 col4 = sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

which in my case gives us:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4
1     1    1    0    0
2    -1    0   -1   -1
3     0   -1    1    0
4    -1   -1    0   -1
5    -1    1    1    1
6     0    0    0    1
7    -1   -1   -1    1
8     1   -1    1   -1
9     0   -1   -1    1
10    0    1    1   -1
```

Now you can easily achieve what you're looking for like this:

```
(df <- df %>% mutate(sums = rowSums(df == 1)))

   col1 col2 col3 col4 sums
1     1    1    0    0    2
2    -1    0   -1   -1    0
3     0   -1    1    0    1
4    -1   -1    0   -1    0
5    -1    1    1    1    3
6     0    0    0    1    1
7    -1   -1   -1    1    1
8     1   -1    1   -1    2
9     0   -1   -1    1    1
10    0    1    1   -1    2
```